# Планировщик заданий Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, vps, windows-server-2012, планировщик-задач

На удаленном сервере (Windows Server 2012) создал задачу которая выполняется каждые 10 минут, все отлично работает. Но, примерно, через 4 часа выполнение задачи прекращается. Я так понимаю сервер "засыпает". Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить сервер или задачу, чтобы она выполнялась постоянно.

Comment: Эммм... покопаться в энергосбережении и отрубить сон?